# When is order modulo m odd or even?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

By order, I mean the smallest integer $r$ such that $a^r$ is congruent to $1$ for some modulo $m$. I know it must divide $\phi(m)$ which is always even.
This question was motivated from a problem I'm currently working on, where I want to find when the order of $10$ mod $p^2$ is even, where $p$ is a prime. For example, the order of $10$ mod $7^2, 11^2, 13^2, 17^2, 23^2, 29^2$ are all even. (that's as far as I checked)

Is there any way that I can reliable find the parity of order modulo $m$. And is there any way to find something related to this problem?

Comment: $a$ is even order modulo $p^2$ if and only if $a$ is even order modulo $p,$ when $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: The order of $10$ $\pmod {31}$ is $15$.  If you are looking for an odd case.  Note that, generally, knowing whether or not $10$ is a square $\pmod p$ is relevant.

Comment: As a rule, if $p-1=2^kn$ where $n$ is odd, then, for $a=1,\dots,p-1,$ exactly $n$ of them will have odd order, so the probability that a random $a$ has even order is $$1-\frac{1}{2^k}.$$ So the more powers of $2$ which divide $p-1,$ the more likely $a$ will have even order.

Comment: So the general case of even order when $m=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k},$ $a$ will have even order modulo $m$ if and only if, for some $i,$ $a$ has even order modulo $p_i^{a_i}.$ When $p$ is an odd prime, then $a$ has even order modulo $p^a$ iff $a$ has even order modulo $p.$ And $a$ has even order modulo $2^a$ if and only if $a\not\equiv 1\pmod{2^a}.$

Comment: The we can reduce the question to when $a$ has even order modulo $p$ when $p$ is an odd prime. We don't really have any tools for this, except in a few cases. When $(p-1)/2$ is odd, $a$ has even order iff $a$ is not a square modulo $p,$ so we can use quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

1. First, let $r$ be the largest integer such that $2^r|p(p-1)$ or equivalently, $2^r|(p-1)$, where $p$ is the prime for which you want to find the parity of the order of $10 \pmod{p^2}$. This integer $r$ can be found efficiently, by first seeing if $4$ divides $p-1$, and if so, then seeing if if $8$ divides $p-1$, and so on. You will only need to check at most $2^{\log p}$ integers $r$ at most.
2. Let $m=\frac{p(p-1)}{2^r}$, where $r$ is as in 1. above. If $10^m \equiv_{p^2} 1$, then the order of $10$ $\pmod{p^2}$ is odd; otherwise the order   order of $10$ $\pmod{p^2}$ is even. [Note that $10^m \pmod{p^2}$ can be found quickly enough by repeated squaring.]
3. FUN FACT: We can really work $\pmod{p}$ instead of $\pmod{p^2}$. AN ALTERNATIVE TO 2. as above: Let $m'=\frac{p-1}{2^r}$ where $r$ is as in 1. and 2. above. Then iff the equation $10^{m'} \equiv_p 1$ holds, then $10^{pm'} = 10^m \equiv_{p^2} 1$  holds. So to conclude: If $10^{m'} \equiv_{p} 1$, then the order of $10$ $\pmod{p^2}$ is odd [no typo, yes the order of $10 \pmod{p^2}$ and not just the order of $10 \pmod p$]; otherwise the order   order of $10$ $\pmod{p^2}$ is even.

Comment: why is the order of $p^2$ $p$ times the order of $p$?

Comment: HINT: Note that $(1+cp)^k$ is $1 \pmod{p^2}$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of $p$, or if $c$ is $0$. You can note this using the Bionomial Thm. If you still aren't convinced 2. above will work.